# How do I get logger to delete existing log file before writing to it again?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, filehandler

Using the configuration below, my logfile will be called 'test-debug.log' and it will grow infinitely for everytime I run the script. I just want this logfile to contain the log records from the most recent run of the script. The log should be deleted before starting again.

How do I do that?

```
logger = logging.getLogger('test') #Create a log with the same name as the script that created it
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')


#Create handlers and set their logging level
filehandler_dbg = logging.FileHandler(logger.name + '-debug.log')
filehandler_dbg.setLevel('DEBUG') 


#Create custom formats of the logrecord fit for both the logfile and the console
streamformatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(levelname)s:\t%(threadName)s:\t%(funcName)s:\t\t%(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S') #We only want to see certain parts of the message


#Apply formatters to handlers
filehandler_dbg.setFormatter(streamformatter)


#Add handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(filehandler_dbg)
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
filehandler_dbg = logging.FileHandler(
   logger.name + '-debug.log', 
   mode='w')
```

to open the filename in `write` mode instead of `append` mode, clobbering `logger.name`

More information: [logging.FileHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) docs, [`open()` and list of modes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Thanks, It now works perfectly.. I had actually looked at the documentation for the `filehandler`, but there was no further information about what and why `mode=a` was the default.. Now I think I understand that it comes from `fileIO` syntax or something like that?

Comment: Exactly. There's a list of all the modes here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: its a shame that the docs for logging don't link back to that functions#open page, that would be really useful.

Comment: If you're using `logging.basicConfig`, adding `filemode='w'` has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any external configuration file then pass 'w' for write mode in args of the handler.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file_handler

[handlers]
keys=file_handler

[handler_file_handler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=formatter
args=("../log/test" + time.strftime("%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S") + '.log', 'w')

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s [%(module)s] %(message)s
```